# Changing some part of a function in a module

Tags: python

In #PSP_soil.py:

```
def evaporation_flux(psi):
    h_s = exp(mw*psi/(R*T)) 
    return(E_p*(h_s-h_a)/(1-h_a))
```

I want to change this function to:

```
def evaporation_flux(psi):
    h_s = exp(mw*psi/(R*T)) 
    return(h_s)
```

but console in spyder (Python 2.7) do not run the program (E_p and h_a are constant variables), and just show    UMD has deleted: PSP_readDataFile, PSP_grid, PSP_ThomasAlgorithm, PSP_soil 
Any advice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
from PSP_soil import *

def evaporation_flux(psi):
    h_s = exp(mw*psi/(R*T)) 
    return(h_s)
```

This redefines `evaporation_flux` from `PSP_soil` so when you do `evaporation_flux(value)`, it gets called.

`from PSP_soil import *` imports all constants you need for this function, but you can also do `from PSP_soil import evaporation_flux, mv, R, T`

Comment: Thank you very much ForceBru. I really appreciate your answer. It is so helpful to me. Thanks again!